# php firebird/interbase external database connection

Tags: php, connection, firebird, interbase

I am trying to connect with an external database (which is located on the same network of mine) via PHP and Firebird, so I used `ibase_connect()`, but I'm not able to connect to the external database.

Below there is my PHP connection :

```
$db = '\\SHARE-NAME\PATH\DATABASE.GDB';
$con = ibase_connect($db , $user , $password) or die(ibase_errmsg());
```

Error message :

> Warning: ibase_connect(): in C:\path\connection.php on line 16
>
> I/O error during "CreateFile (open)" operation for file "C:\SHARE-NAME\PATH\DATABASE.GDB" Error while trying to open file Le chemin d'accès spécifié est introuvable.

Does `ibase_connect` allow external connection ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a Firebird server installed on that remote external database and then you can connect with

```
HOSTNAME:C:/PATH/DATABASE.FDB
```

Firebird can't access databases on remote windows shares

http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq46/